# negative object length possible in JavaScript or underscore.js? meaning?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I was looking at the source code for the [Underscore.js](https://web.archive.org/web/20130403134123/http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) library, specifically for the [map](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js) method (around line 85 on that page, and copied here):

```
  _.map = function(obj, iterator, context) {
    var results = [];
    if (obj == null) return results;
    if (nativeMap && obj.map === nativeMap) return obj.map(iterator, context);
    each(obj, function(value, index, list) {
      results[results.length] = iterator.call(context, value, index, list);
    });
    if (obj.length === +obj.length) results.length = obj.length;
    return results;
  };
```

completely straightforward EXCEPT for the following line

```
    if (obj.length === +obj.length) results.length = obj.length;
```

Now, I read this to mean "if the object length is not a negative number..."
which, if my interpretation is right, implies that it might be!

So, dear experts, for what kinds of objects might

```
    obj.length === +obj.length
```

be `false`?  My understanding of `===` means it could return `false` if the type of `obj.length` didn't match the type of `+obj.length`, but here my knowledge falls short.  What kinds of things could `+` do to the kinds of things that `obj.length` might be?  Is `x === +x` some sort of generic idiomatic test that I just don't know?  Is it response to some sort of special case that arises deeper in underscore.js, e.g., does underscore.js assign and track negative object.lengths for some conventional purpose?  Guidance and advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that `+x` is *not* necessarily positive--it's just the numerical value of `x`. So if `var x = -10`, `+x` is also `-10`.

Comment: Yes, realize that +x did not do anything to the value of x (didn't increment it temporarily for the comparison).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that's testing to see if `typeof obj.length === 'number'`

As opposed to if it's an object that has a length value of `'2 days'`

So it knows if it's an object like:

```
var obj = { app: 'doctor', length: '45 min' };
```

vs

```
var obj = [ 0, 2, 1];
```

Comment: I see -- I think.  If `obj = { app: 'doctor', length: '45 min' }` then `obj.length` will be `undefined`, and `+obj.Length` will be `NaN`.  But if `obj` is an array, then its length will be a positive number and all will be well.  So this is really a test of array-ness.  Now the question is "why not `obj instanceof Array`?

Comment: obj.length won't be undefined because there is a specific length property in obj and its value is '45 min'.  But it would be nasty to use that as a length.

Answer (score 4):

In javascript, the `+` operator can also be used to convert a string representation of a number to a number. So the line:

```
obj.length === +obj.length
```

can also mean: "length is a number and not a string".